# Electron-React App---WebSocket connection failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Tags: reactjs, websocket, electron

I'm building a React-Electron App. Now I have several React pages linked to different url:

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Demo />} />
      <Route path="/SumView" element={<Sum_layout />} />
      <Route path="/Frequency" element={<Sum_layout />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

and in electron side, this is app has 2 child windows.

In main.js, I have:

`win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');`
`SumViewChild.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/SumView');`
`FrequencyChild.loadURL('http://localhost:3000/Frequency');`

In the code, after I changed the "dark theme" parameter, I need the page to reload to apply the different css document in React side.
so I use

```js
win.reload();
SumViewChild.reload();
FrequencyChild.reload();
```

in my main.js.

Now when I want to reload the pages, something weird happens. The app is meant to do data visualization. If the program haven't read any data from backend, it can change theme and reload correctly. After it read some data from backend and displayed it, when change theme and reloading, it occurs":

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE`

by the way this is my web preference setting:

```js
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true,
  contextIsolation: false,
  enableRemoteModule: true,
  allowFileAccess: true,
  nativeWindowOpen:true,
}
```

I have googled a lot but still don't know what happened in my code and what cause the weird behaviour. If there is some security issue or cross-domain, why it works fine when no data is read?